# wso2apim configure scopes with roles that have white spaces

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I had tried configure scopes with wso2apim, but my ldap groups has spaces in their names, someone already had that problem?

Someone know how to fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what is the problem, in the package: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.handlers

The class ScopesIssuer, has the line code:

```
List<String> roleList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(roles.replaceAll(" ", "").split(",")));
```

Where the role list suffer a replace and all spaces are removed from the list, this cause problems with groups with white spaces, I have replace this logic and resolv that problem.

Version: APIM 1.9.1

Thank you.